# rails named_scope and :source

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, named

I am a beginner in Rails,

Can we use `:source` with named scope?

I am able to use it with has_many and other associations

Thanks
Mark

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't because you don't need.
A named scope is part of the model where defined in.

```
class Post
  named_scope :published, :conditions => { :published => true }
end
```

However, this doesn't prevent you from using a named scope through an association.

```
class Category
  has_many :posts
end

category.posts # => all posts
category.posts.published # only published posts
```

Comment: This approach, however, completely ignores Law of Demeter, one of the main benefits of has_many => through

Answer (score 0):

If you can use it in a find() call, generally you can use it with a named scope. The parameters for find are itemized in the documentation (http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find/class) but I'm not sure that source is one of them. As far as I know, that's for a has_many relationship sort of thing, not for find.

However, named scopes can be applied to relationships, so perhaps that's what you're intending.